# Tensorflow Initialize list with 0s and 1s similar to tf.one_hot

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I currently have a list of values over a time sequence say the values are `[1, 3, 5, 7, 3]`. Currently I am using tf.one_hot to get a one hot vector/tensor representative for each value within the list.

```
1 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In Tensorflow is there a way/function that would allow me to do something similar but initialize all values from 0 to the value with 1s?

Desired Result:

```
1 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
7 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
3 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `tf.sequence_mask`.

[TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask)

Comment: Awesome :) I tried looking through all of their functions but I must have missed it! Thank you very much!